# Calculating how long arc second is for given long/lat?

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude

I am wondering what area is covered by a dataset which is one arc second wide.

Comment: Neither your title nor your body state clearly what you're after, and they even ask for different things.

Answer (score 4):

At sea level at the equator:

One degree of longitude is about 111km

One minute of longitude is one sixtieth of that: about 1.85km

One second of longitude is one sixtieth of that amount: about 31 meters or 100 feet.

However:

> Arc-seconds of latitude remain nearly constant, while arc-seconds of
>   longitude decrease in a trigonometric cosine-based fashion as one
>   moves toward the earth's poles.

Arc seconds aren't really a great way to measure distance. Is there no possibility of using a ruler tool in your GIS or any kind of distance function?

**Sources**:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_minute

http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0400/wdside.html

Comment: Filled in some missing data -- hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

1 nautical mile is one minute of arc. At equatorial sea level, this
is equivalent to 1852m/60 = 30.86666667m (the equatorial arc-second).

As noted above, this distance will become smaller as one moves towards the poles.

At 33.6º latitude South, cos 33º = 0.83292,
cos 33.6 * 30.866666667m = 25.709m for arc-second of longitude at this latitude (33.6º, approximately)

Comment: As a bash script:

DEGS_TO_RADS=0.017453293

EQUAT_ARC_SECOND_METERS=30.866666667

    $ seq 90 -5 1 | while read D ; do echo "$EQUAT_ARC_SECOND_METERS * c($DEGS_TO_RADS * $D)" | bc -l | sed "s|^|$D degrees : |;s|$| meters per arc seconds|" ; done

90 degrees : 0 meters

85 degrees : 2.690030000 meters

80 degrees : 5.359688000 meters

75 degrees : 7.988602000 meters